# Grouping shortened string and unshortened string from a case expression into a count

Tags: sql-server, group-by, count

Sorry if I don't explain this very well or haven't given enough info.

I am trying to combine figures using count but I am running into a problem where the data from my case expression isn't grouping together.

The case statement is required to handle different types of codes with prefixes in the NUMBER column that need removing:

```
T123456
123456
```

This is an example of the code:

SELECT 
    case 
    when left(NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(NUMBER, 6) 
    else NUMBER 
    end as User, Count(login)
from Access 
group by 
    case 
    when left(NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(NUMBER, 6) 
    else NUMBER 
    end

My query should return a grouping of the "number" to provide a combined total and not two separate rows.

```
This:
123456  10
Not this:
123456  7
123456  3
```

Comment: Do you use this case statement both in select and group by?

Comment: You should post the complete query.

Comment: I've tried to expand above if that helps. The original query is quite big so won't show it all, i think above is essentially what i need to fix.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose your query is

```
SEELCT case 
when left(NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(NUMBER, 6) 
else NUMBER 
end as User, col1
FROM table
```

please change it to:

```
SEELCT case 
when left(NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(NUMBER, 6) 
else NUMBER 
end as User, SUM(col1)
FROM table
GROUP BY case 
when left(NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(NUMBER, 6) 
else NUMBER 
end
```

Comment: Thanks for your help but I think there must be something else wrong with my query that I haven't included looking at this answer. I have other columns referencing other tables with isnulls so maybe that is making the rows more distinct.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry for the lack of info i shared on this, i have found the answer now.

This is a better interpretation of my query:

`SELECT 
case when left(A.NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(A.NUMBER, 6) else NUMBER 
end as User, Count(a.login) from Access A
Left join Logins L
On L.LoginID = A.number
group by case when left(NUMBER,1) = 't' then RIGHT(NUMBER, 6) else NUMBER end`

Eventually had a brainwave about the "On" clause and joined it with the case statement above it

Now it groups all the same numbers together